K6 Tests - Summary Output to include timestamps
I have a K6 test that is running multiple scenarios. I would like to export the test summary to Elastic and as part of it, would like to include the start and end times for the test run. I am trying to set these values inside my default function but then the values don't stick when i get to  the handleSummary() method.
`let startTime;
export default function () {
.. all scenarios and at the end i have a check
    if (!startTime){
        startTime = exec.scenario.startTime;
    }
}`

export async function handleSummary(data) { console.log("Start Time", startTime); }
The startTime is undefined inside my handleSummary method. Has anyone tried this before? Is there a better/easier way to get this info in the summary method?
Thank you in advance!

Each k6 VU (virtual user) is independent and you cannot share data between two VUs. Each VU fully parses your test script file, executes any code in your init context (the part outside the exported functions), and then executes your test function repeatedly.
You can think of the setup, teardown, and handleSummary lifecycle functions as "special VUs": they do not share data nor state with any other VU, but some can return data and others can receive data as a function parameter.
Unfortunately, the start time of the scenarios is not available in the object passed to handleSummary. It only contains state.testRunDurationMs which coudl be used to calculate the approximate start time of the test (not each scenario, mind you).

Thank you, Is it possible to use the output from one test/group as input to the next test/group?

@sg2000 What exactly do you mean with test/group? group simply returns the value of its callback and you can use it any way you want

Sorry i meant the default function has multiple groups, one per test. I wanted to know if i can use the output from one group/test on the next one. You are right. I was able to get the data and use it subsequently. Thank you
